# Ways to regain Oath of Enmity with a multiclass Avenger?

Tags: dnd-4e

The 2 multiclass Avenger feats, Disciple of Divine Wrath from PHB 2 and Hero of Faith from Divine Power, contain the following text:

> Once per encounter, you can use the avenger’s oath of enmity power. The effect lasts until the end of your next turn. (Disciple of Divine Wrath)

and

> Once per encounter, you can use the oath of enmity power. The effect lasts until you hit the target or until the target drops to 0 hit points. You cannot switch the target or extend the duration of the power in any way. (Hero of Faith)

1) If a character takes both of these feats, are they still limited to one OoE per encounter, or can they use it twice?

2) If a character has Divine Mastery (see below), do they regain the above once per encounter use?

> When you spend an action point to take an extra action, you also regain the use of a divine encounter power you have used during this encounter. (Divine Mastery- from Divine Power)

Answer (score 2):

1) You can use it twice, one of them limited to one hit, the other unlimited number of attacks until the end of your next turn.

You can take as many multiclass feats as you want, but they must be for the same class. Otherwise feats like Battle Acumen would not work. PHB page 208.
That said this is a bad investment, Disciple of Divine Wrath is ok, but Hero of Faith is really weak.

2) Oath of Enmity is definitely a power, the online compendium lists it as such, and check the last sentence of its description:

> If an effect lets you reroll an attack roll and you rolled twice because of ***this power***, you reroll both dice.

So you it satisfies every criterium of Divine Mastery, you can regain it.
Again, it can be done, just not worth it.

Comment: I'm not so certain about Divine Mastery being of use. Oath of Emnity's own effect already lets you regain use of it; the limitation on uses/encounter isn't because it's an encounter power, it's because the MC feat specifically says once per encounter, like a leader's At-Will heal might say 2 times per encounter.

Comment: Interesting point, but there are some powers (Assassin's Strike for example) specifically telling you it can not be regained. Disciple of Divine Wrath does not do so. I think the initial limit of Disciple of Divine Wrath does not prohibit any regain.

Comment: Of course it is ambigious enough for any DM to limit it, but regaining it with Divine Mastery is so underpowered there is no real reason to ban it.